# g++ wont compile std=c++0x under Snow Leopard

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, osx-snow-leopard

Having an old Intel Core Duo MacBook with Snow Leopard, when I try to compile using g++ and the input parameter std=c++0x I get:

```
cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=c++0x"
```

Any ideas of how to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

c++0x / c++11 support has only been added starting with gcc v4.3, see [this page](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html) to check what c++ feature has been added in what gcc version.

Alternatively you could use the clang++ compiler, which also comes standard with XCode. See [this page](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html) for version info.

Or install gcc47 from [macports](http://www.macports.org/)

Btw, better use `-std=c++11`,  the `c++0x` option is not supported by clang.

Comment: Of course when working with g++ the `-std=c++11` (unlike `c++0x`) is only supported since g++4.7, so for the near future the decision on what is better depends on what compiler you need to be compatible to.

Comment: gcc/g++ on a macports install is installed as g++-mp-v, where v is the version#. you can immediately check if you have any mp versions by typing gcc-mp and hitting tab for tab completion, or g++-mp and doing the same.